# I have Zip function error while merging lists in to tuple in python

Tags: python

```
cars = ["Audi","BMW","Lamborghini","McLaren","Mercedes-Benz","Porsche","Rolls-Royce","Tesla","Volvo"]
models= ['R8','i8' ,'Aventedor', "P2", "AMG", "GT3 RS", "Ghost", "model S", "XC90"]
print zip(cars,models)

error: print zip(cars,models)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Legends! What is wrong with my code?

Comment: It's not zip... `print` use to be a statement in 2.x versions of Python but hasn't been for quite some time now (current version of Python is 3.10) - it looks like you're following some code from 15 years ago... (it's a function now... so `print(zip(cars, model))` - but `zip` is also lazy now so you'll need to do something to expand it out...

Answer (score 4):

print() is a function as per Python Version 3.
Here is the corrected code:

```
cars = ["Audi","BMW","Lamborghini","McLaren","Mercedes-Benz","Porsche","Rolls-Royce","Tesla","Volvo"]
models= ['R8','i8' ,'Aventedor', "P2", "AMG", "GT3 RS", "Ghost", "model S", "XC90"]
result = zip(cars,models)
print(list(result))
```

Output:

> [('Audi', 'R8'), ('BMW', 'i8'), ('Lamborghini', 'Aventedor'),('McLaren', 'P2'), ('Mercedes-Benz', 'AMG'), ('Porsche', 'GT3 RS'),('Rolls-Royce', 'Ghost'), ('Tesla', 'model S'), ('Volvo', 'XC90')]

Answer (score 0):

print(...) but you also need to make it a list before printing because zip creates a generator object

```
print(list(zip(cars,models)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each list contains the same number of elements and that you're trying to print make and model together per line of output then:

```
cars = ["Audi","BMW","Lamborghini","McLaren","Mercedes-Benz","Porsche","Rolls-Royce","Tesla","Volvo"]
models= ['R8','i8' ,'Aventedor', "P2", "AMG", "GT3 RS", "Ghost", "model S", "XC90"]

for car, model in zip(cars, models):
    print(car, model)
```

Note the syntax for the print() function

Answer (score 0):

```
cars = ["Audi","BMW","Lamborghini","McLaren","Mercedes-Benz","Porsche","Rolls-Royce","Tesla","Volvo"]
models= ['R8','i8' ,'Aventedor', "P2", "AMG", "GT3 RS", "Ghost", "model S", "XC90"]
    
tuple(zip(cars,models))
```

Perfect this code works!!! Thanks a lot guys ! Keep rocking